# How to make Python CGI script capture user input as variable

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am running a Python CGI script from web browser to collect some data from a network device and at the moment the IP address of network device is static(10.0.0.120).

Below is the Python CGI script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "content-type: json\n\n"
import json
from napalm import get_network_driver
driver = get_network_driver('ios')
hub2 = driver('10.0.0.120', 'admin', 'admin')
hub2.open()

ios_output = hub2.get_facts();
print json.dumps(ios_output, indent=5);
hub2.close()
```

Here is the HTML code

```
         <ul>
      <li><a href="http://172.17.0.2/cgi-bin/info.cgi" target="_blank">Device Facts</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://172.17.0.2/cgi-bin/arp.cgi" target="_blank">Device Arp Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://172.17.0.2/cgi-bin/mac.cgi" target="_blank">Switch MAC Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://172.17.0.2/cgi-bin/lldp.cgi" target="_blank">lldp Neighbors</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Now the goal is to get the ip address from user who is accessing this webpage and then use it in the above mentioned Python CGI script in place of 10.0.0.120.

Any thoughts or suggestions or tweaks ...

Thanks in advance